# Evaluate the following definite integral $\int_{0}^t\cos(\sin s)\, ds$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate
$$\int_{0}^t\cos(\sin s)\, ds\ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ \int_0^{\sin t}\frac{\cos p \, dp}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}.$$
Please help how to start.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos%28sin%28x%29%29) says that there is no result in terms of standard mathematical functions for $\int\cos(\sin x)\,d x$, so you can only try numerical methods.

Comment: I suspect this is related to elliptic integrals.

Comment: How about [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion)?
$e^{iz\sin\theta} = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(z) e^{in\theta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed in the comments, we can use [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion):
$$\cos(\sin(s)) = J_0(1)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(1)\cos(2ns).$$
Integrating with respect to $s$, we obtain:
$$I = \int_0^t\cos(\sin(s))ds = t\left(J_0(1)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(1)\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2nt}\right).$$

Maybe the only cases with closed form solution are for $t = k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$, when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(1)\frac{\sin(2\pi n)}{2\pi n}=0$, in which case $I=k\pi J_0(1)\approx 2.40393943k$.

Somehow interesting, since $\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2nt}\leq \frac{1}{2nt}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(1) = \frac{1-J_0(1)}{2}$, we can upper bound the integral as
$$I = \color{red}{\int_0^t\cos(\sin(s))ds} = tJ_0(1)+2t\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n}(1)\frac{\sin(2nt)}{2nt}\leq tJ_0(1)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_{2n}(1)}{2n}<\color{blue}{(t-1)J_0(1)+1},$$

thus the dominant term is $tJ_0(1)$ (see the picture).

[image]